# Split Dataframe by size, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I want to split dataframe into 30MB different dataset. Then I need to export to csv file.

```
FileSize = SQLData.memory_usage(index=True, deep=False).sum())
FileSizeMB = FileSize/1038336
if FileSizeMB > 30:
  # Want to split data frame below 30MB.
  # Export splitted Dataframe
else:
    SQLData.to_csv(r'D:\Export\SQLData.csv', sep=',', index=False, na_rep='NA')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recursive solution:

```
# solution
def save_file_part(df, size_threshold, save_path, part_number=0):
    file_size = df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=False).sum() / 1038336
    num_records = len(df)

    if file_size > size_threshold:
        records_to_split_off = int(num_records * size_threshold // file_size)
        df_to_save = df.head(records_to_split_off)
        df_to_save.to_csv(save_path.format(part_number),sep=',', index=False, na_rep='NA')
        save_file_part(df.tail(num_records-records_to_split_off), size_threshold, save_path, part_number=part_number+1)

    else:
        df.to_csv(save_path.format(part_number), sep=',', index=False, na_rep='NA')


# example
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=60000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60000,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
file_size = df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=False).sum() / 1038336
print(file_size)

save_file_part(df, 0.5, save_path="c:/tmp/my_df_{}.csv") # note, the function expects "save_path" as a string with at least one "{}" placeholder
```

df.memory_usage tells you how large the pandas DataFrame is in memory. When you save a csv the size will differ (will be larger), so you might want to set `size_threshold` to something like 15 Mb. You could figure out an appropriate size with a script, but you might as well just experiment a bit to find the correct ration